# How to cover n sites with the smallest number of fixed radius balls?

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, combinatorial-optimization, covering

Given $n$ "data points" in $d$ (Euclidean) space

$$\mathbf{x}_j \in \mathbb{R}^d, \text{ for } j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$$

how does one find the smallest integer $m$ such that there exists $m$ "centre points"

$$\mathbf{c}_i \in \mathbb{R}^d, \text{ for } i \in \{1,\dots,m\}$$

where for each data point the closest centre is within a given radius $r$

$$r^2 \ge \min^{m}_{i=1} \|\mathbf{x}_j - \mathbf{c}_i\|^2, \forall j \in \{1,\dots,n\} $$

?

I think this is similar to or the same as the [geometric set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_set_cover_problem). In my case, the centre locations are *not* drawn from a discrete set but rather they are free points in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

I have a "bottom-up" merge-based heuristic that seems to work well in 2D, but would like to know if any known algorithms exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take your given radius $r$ to be $1$, I believe your problem is known as *covering points by unit balls*, or the *unit covering problem*. Covering by two unit balls was shown
to be NP-complete by Megiddo, by reduction from 3SAT:

> Megiddo, Nimrod. "On the complexity of some geometric problems in unbounded dimension." *Journal of Symbolic Computation* 10.3-4 (1990): 327-334.
>   ([PDF download](http://theory.stanford.edu/~megiddo/pdf/unboundim.pdf).)

However, a polynomial-time approximation scheme (PTAS), in any
fixed dimension, is available:

> Hochbaum, Dorit S., and Wolfgang Maass. "Approximation schemes for covering and packing problems in image processing and VLSI." *Journal of the ACM* (JACM) 32.1 (1985): 130-136.
>   ([PDF download](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.93.6936&rep=rep1&type=pdf).)

Many variations have been studied, e.g., "capacitated covering with unit balls,"
where the points have weights and each covering ball can cover no more than
a weight sum of $1$; or versions that involve coloring restrictions.

---

[image]

          

<sup>Image from [StackOverflow post by user *dfens*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25424329/387778).</sup>

---